# Filter out first comma and everything before it using split

Tags: javascript, split

I'm trying to filter out the first comma and everything before it. Should I just use regex or will split work?

```
// notice multiple commas, I'm trying to grab everything after the first comma.
str = 'jibberish, text cat dog milk, chocolate, rainbow, snow',

// this gets the text from the first comma but I want everything after it. =(
result = str.split(',')[0];
```

Comment: I removed the [tag:jquery] tag, since this really has nothing to do with jQuery :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of split, try this - it will not mess with any other commas than the first

```
var result = str.substring(str.indexOf(",")+1)
```

If you want to skip the leading space, use +2

If you are not sure there will always be a comma, it is safer to do trim

```
var result = str.substring(str.indexOf(",")+1).trim();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the substring to extract the desired string.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/bxkVM/1/)**

```
result = str.substring(str.indexOf(',')+1); //add 2 if you want to remove leading space
```

*If you want to use split for any reason*

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/bxkVM/)**

```
result = str.split(',')[0];    
result = str.split(result+",")[1];
```

Comment: If you will do this a huge number of time on the same page there may be a difference in performance

Comment: Thanks @mplungjan, updated my answer, I did not removed as in question he asks "I'm trying to filter out the first comma and everything before it"

Answer (score 1):

```
// Convert to array
var arr = str.split(',');

// Remove first element of array
arr.splice(0, 1);

// Convert back to string
var newString = arr.join(', ');
```

Comment: This will lose any spaces there used to be after any other comma

Comment: Which will add any spaces to commas that did not have them such as 1,000,000

Comment: Which will not happen because the string specified does not contain numbers over a thousand...

Answer (score 1):

How about using [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) and [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf):

```
str = str.substring(str.indexOf(",") + 2);
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ymuJc/1/

Comment: Point of interest: `Array.indexOf()` as well as `String.indexOf()` is not supported in IE7.

Comment: String.indexOf is supported by all browsers since ie4 and ns3

Answer (score 0):

you can use `substr` and `indexOf`

```
str = 'jibberish, text cat dog milk, chocolate, rainbow, snow'

result = str.substr(str.indexOf(',')+1, str.length)
```

Comment: No need for the second parm and your result will have a leading space